# MacVim not letting me save files without giving warning

Tags: vim

Each time I save (`:w`) this warning comes up:

```
E510 can't make backupfile.
```

`/.vimrc` includes

```
set backupdir=/.vim/backups   
set dir=/.vim/backups
```

Those locations exist and I have write permissions to those files.

`:verbose set backupdir?` says

```
Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

I went into the `/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-137/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim` directory, made sure I had permissions there in case that was an issue, looked at the `vimrc` file there and saw nothing about backupdir.

I am tempted to uninstall and reinstall mccvim with home-brew but I am not sure if that will do the job. I prefer not to

```
set: no backup
```

but essentially that is what I have now since I can only save with `:w`!

I have Vim version 8.0 on Mac Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: It seems unlikely those directories would exist. What's the output of `ls -ld /.vim/backups`?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x+ 55 jk  staff  1870 Sep 23 21:15  **** but ls -a shows .vim. Not sure how to interpret that. I can cd to .vim, and ls to see "backups", "colors", "swaps" and "undo"

Comment: What do you mean, ****? Where's the rest of the line?

Comment: sorry:  ls: /.vim/backups: No such file or directory

Comment: OK, then it looks like you're confusing `/` and `~`. `/` is the root directory, `~` is your home directory. You probably want `set backupdir=~/.vim/backups`.

Comment: I tried that, opened a new vim file, and got same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155172/discussion-between-cumin-and-melpomene).

Comment: Just rechecked everything; your solution did fix it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing `/` and `~`. And a bunch of other things…

The former represents the root of your filesystem, to which you almost certainly not have write privileges if you are not `root`.

The latter represents your "home" directory, to which you have write privilege. Your "home" can be represented with:

```
$HOME
~
/Users/username
```

So, taking your question one part at a time…

> Each time I save (`:w`) this warning comes up:
>
> ```
> E510 can't make backupfile.
> ```

It means that you can't write to the directory where Vim stores its backup files.

> `/.vimrc` includes
>
> ```
> set backupdir=/.vim/backups
> set dir=/.vim/backups
> ```
>
> Those locations exist and I have write permissions to those files.

- You *may* have a `~/.vimrc` (a `.vimrc` in your "home") but almost certainly not a `/.vimrc` (a `.vimrc` at the root of your filesystem).

  The right place for your `vimrc` is either:

  - `~/.vimrc`,
  - `~/.vim/vimrc` (no dot!).
- Your settings tell Vim that it should write backup files in `/.vim/backups` but there are a few problems with that.

  Problems include:

  - `/.vim/` almost certainly doesn't exist,
  - `/.vim/backups/` is therefore very unlikely to exist,
  - your normal user almost certainly doesn't have the right to write in `/` anyway.

Assuming the `~/.vim/` directory exists, those options should be:

```
set backupdir=~/.vim/backups
set dir=~/.vim/backups
```

> `:verbose set backupdir?` says
>
> ```
> Last set from ~/.vimrc
> ```

Yeah, no problem here.

> I went into the `/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-137/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim` directory, made sure I had permissions there in case that was an issue, looked at the `vimrc` file there and saw nothing about backupdir.

What makes you think anything in Vim's runtime files has anything to do with your issue? Vim told you `Last set from ~/.vimrc` so there's nowhere else to look.

> I am tempted to uninstall and reinstall mccvim with home-brew but I am not sure if that will do the job. I prefer not to
>
> ```
> set: no backup
> ```
>
> but essentially that is what I have now since I can only save with `:w`!

Reinstalling MacVim won't change anything. **Taking an introductory course on the UNIX shell is definitely a better idea.**

Also, did you mean `:set nobackup`? And I'm not sure "since I can only save with `:w`" means anything.